# cakephp routes with optional parameter

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have these two configurations in my routes.php

```
Router::connect('/messages/:type', array('controller' => 'messages', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('type'), 'type' => 'inbox|sent|starred|trash' ) );    

Router::connect('/messages/:type/:page', array('controller' => 'messages', 'action' => 'index'), array('pass' => array('type', 'page'), 'type' => 'inbox|sent|starred|trash', 'page' => '[\d]+' ) );
```

I want to make only one rule from these two. It seems that just using `'page' => '[\d]*'` or `'page' => '[\d]?'` should work, but it does not. When I try to access the first page - which is `/messages/inbox` it says `inbox` action not defined, so as it turns out even if by regular expression we tell cake that the page number either exists or no, after all it understands that rule only if the `page` param exists in url. Is there a way to handle this ?

cake version 2.4

Thanks

Comment: Try with pattern for page `'page'=> '[\d]{0,}'` and in your index method place a default value `public function message($type, $page=0) {`

Comment: @Georgi, Thanks for the answer, but does not work, the same error. btw the action's default values I had set.

Comment: if you want to do the pagination with cakephp you can do this by `querystring` parameters instead of `named` parameters